# MS Access SQL – How can I count the occurrence of a number from one table in strings of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

In MS Access 365 I have 2 tables and I want to count the occurrence of a year from the first table in part of a string of the second table, purely with SQL (so far I used VBA, but I want to simplify).

The first table (tDistinctYears) contains all the years, in which one of our members paid:

| ID | PaymentYear |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 |
| 2 | 2016 |
| 3 | 2017 |
| 3 | 2018 |
| 4 | 2019 |
| 5 | 2020 |
| 6 | 2021 |
| 7 | 2022 |

The second table (tPayments) has all payments from members with one column containing a membership number and the other one containing payment years. Sometimes a member pays for one year, sometime for several years. The table therefore looks like that:

| MembershipNr | YearPayment |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2016 |
| 11 | 2017 |
| 11 | 2018 |
| 26 | 2017 |
| 26 | 2018;2019 |
| 26 | 2020;2021;2022 |
| 38 | 2016 |
| 38 | 2017 |
| 38 | 2018;2019;2020;2021 |

I want a query which tells me how many members paid in which year:

| PaymentYear | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2015 | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 |
| 2017 | 3 |
| 2018 | 3 |
| 2019 | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2021 | 2 |

I used the following SQL query, which I found using various answers on stackoverflow:

```sql
SELECT tDistinctYears.PaymentYear, (COUNT(tPayments.YearPayment)) AS [Count]
   FROM tDistinctYears
   LEFT JOIN tPayments ON tDistinctYears.PaymentYear like "*" & tPayments.YearPayment & "*"
       WHERE (tDistinctYears.PaymentYear > 0 AND tDistinctYears.PaymentYear <= YEAR(NOW()))
   GROUP BY tDistinctYears.PaymentYear;
```

But what I get is this:

| PaymentYear | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2015 | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 |
| 2017 | 3 |
| 2018 | 1 |
| 2019 | 0 |
| 2020 | 0 |
| 2021 | 0 |

It seems as if the above query does not use the “like” expression in the JOIN ON section.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close just alter column in where condition `tPayments.YearPayment` should be first and `tDistinctYears.PaymentYear` should be inside like operator.

```
SELECT tDistinctYears.PaymentYear, (COUNT(tPayments.YearPayment)) AS [Count]
FROM tDistinctYears
LEFT JOIN tPayments ON tPayments.YearPayment like "*" & 
tDistinctYears.PaymentYear
& "*" WHERE (tDistinctYears.PaymentYear > 0 AND tDistinctYears.PaymentYear <= 
YEAR(NOW()))
GROUP BY tDistinctYears.PaymentYear;
```

Comment: Thanks Nagib – works perfect, though I don’t understand the logic behind it right away. I will need to study that a bit more to get full insights. Have a good day – you made mine great already.

Comment: To explain this look at the data. when you say in query that `2018` like `2018;2019` it will return result but when you say  `2018;2019` like `2018` it will not return data.